# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT and flip two rows in one

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have table

```
id | industry_id | type | key
1        1           0    word1
2        1           1    word2
3        1           0    word3
4        1           1    word4
5        2           0    word5
6        2           1    hello
7        2           0    world
```

In result i need to get table

```
industry_id | title       | description
1           | word1 word3 | word2 word4
2           | word5 world | hello
```

It means that all words with type 0 go to title, with type 1 to description

For now i can get almost what i want with query (but still get 2 records for each industry)

```
SELECT industry_id, type, GROUP_CONCAT(`key` SEPARATOR ' ') AS TEXT FROM table GROUP BY industry_id, type
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)

Comment: the fact is there is no application level, I have the table and want to get sphinx index with structure as desired output, and all i can do for that is to write a SQL query in sphinx config. If no good solution exists i can probably create a temp table with php and use it for sphinx, but that way it will be harder to update sphinx index if initial table will change

Comment: using `DISTINCT` is not helping??

Comment: I dont understand how DISTINCT can help me. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `industry_id, type` so you will get 4 rows and two row for each industry id try this

```
SELECT industry_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `type`=0 THEN `key` END SEPARATOR ' ') AS title,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `type`=1 THEN `key` END SEPARATOR ' ') AS description
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY industry_id
```

### [See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bc62/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
SELECT industry_id, type, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(type = 0,key,'') SEPARATOR ' ') AS title,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(type = 1,key,'') SEPARATOR ' ') AS description
   FROM table GROUP BY industry_id, type
```

Comment: You might want to use NULL instead of `''` to avoid results like `word1     word2  word3`. Also in this case ordering the words will probably be needed.

Comment: Still get 2 rows for each industry, almost the same outpup as in query in my initial post, but have 2 fields (title and description) instead of one `text`, and one of them is empty (depending on type)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT industry_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 0 THEN text END) title
     , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN text END) description
  FROM
     ( SELECT industry_id
            , type
            , GROUP_CONCAT(`key` SEPARATOR ' ') TEXT 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY industry_id
            , type
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY industry_id;
```

Consider renaming your `key` column!